# "No rule to make target `install`" error when using make install

Tags: c, gcc, debian

I'm trying to install sia-hsd alarm system,
[github link](https://github.com/bitlair/siahsd)

up to that ./configure output is

```
Setting top to                           : /home/siahsd-master
Setting out to                           : /home/siahsd-master/build
Checking for program gcc,cc              : gcc
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar
Checking for program pkg-config          : /usr/bin/pkg-config
Checking for 'glib-2.0'                  : yes
Checking for 'talloc'                    : yes
Checking for 'tevent'                    : yes
Checking for 'samba-util'                : yes
Checking for 'ndr'                       : yes
Checking for header stdio.h              : yes
Checking for header stdlib.h             : yes
Checking for header stdint.h             : yes
Checking for header stdbool.h            : yes
Checking for header sys/time.h           : yes
Checking for header sys/types.h          : yes
Checking for header sys/stat.h           : yes
Checking for header netinet/in.h         : yes
Checking for header arpa/inet.h          : yes
Checking for header unistd.h             : yes
Checking for header string.h             : yes
Checking for header fcntl.h              : yes
Checking for header errno.h              : yes
Checking for header talloc.h             : yes
Checking for header glib.h               : yes
Checking for header glibconfig.h         : yes
Checking for header dbi/dbi.h            : yes
Checking for header util/data_blob.h     : yes
Checking for header core/ntstatus.h      : yes
Checking for header charset.h            : yes
Checking for library dbi                 : yes
Checking for library talloc              : yes
Checking for library ndr                 : yes
Checking for library gmp                 : yes
Checking for library hogweed             : yes
Checking for library nettle              : yes
'configure' finished successfully (2.057s)
```

output of make "CPP=gcc -E -ffreestanding" command is below

```
[21/27] cstlib: build/jsonbot.c.7.o -> build/libjsonbot.a
[22/27] cstlib: build/siahs.c.6.o -> build/libsiahs.a
[23/27] cstlib: build/sia.c.5.o -> build/libsia.a
[24/27] cstlib: build/config.c.4.o -> build/libconfig.a
[25/27] cprogram: build/chirond.c.10.o build/ndr_chiron.c.10.o -> build/chirond
[26/27] cprogram: build/siahsd.c.8.o -> build/siahsd
[27/27] cprogram: build/secipd.c.9.o build/crc16.c.9.o build/ndr_secip.c.9.o -> build/secipd
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/siahsd-master/build'
'build' finished successfully (3.389s)
```

When I'm using the make install command, I got this error :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Any idea about how to solve it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `C` and `C++` are different. Please do not tag the question with both.

Comment: is there target named install in Makefile?

Comment: This is not a programming question. It's also not a question which contains enough information to give a meaningful answer (like, what are you even to install? What is a "sia-hsd"? What is the *full* error output, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the Makefile doesn't contain a "*install*" target, thus make does not know how to make it. Taking a look at the waf build file, that doesn't provide any clue on how the install target should be implemented. Apparently installation is not required after building the software, just run it.

You could implement the "dist" target in the Makefile to see what it actually packages. Maybe that provides a hint on what should be installed.

```
dist:
    @bin/waf dist
```

Comment: thanks will check it and can you tell me how to run it. i mean which file i have to run.

Comment: If you add the mentioned lines to the "Makefile" you should be able to run "make dist" much like you ran the other make command.
Do make sure to use a 'tab' character for the indentation though, also have a blank line after the added lines.